# How do I capture the type of Generic object in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, silverlight, types, runtime, capture

I have a method that returns an ObservableCollection on any type
say

```
ObservableCollection<Type1>
ObservableCollection<Type2>
ObservableCollection<Type3>
```

i want to be able to capture the Type (Type1, Type2, Type3) of that at run-time when that how do i do it?

what i mean at run time is the objects returned are different at runtime and i should be able to catpure the Type and execute an approprate function ( using switch case )

Comment: what do you mean with "capture the type at runtime"?

Comment: I suggest you edit the original question to answer Daniel's comment.  Stecya's answer seems right, but the question is still ambiguous.  Could you add a code sample showing what your function's return type is, and what type of data/variable you're trying to get from it?

Comment: @Daniel @Merlyn what i mean at run time is the objects returned are different at runtime and i should be able to catpure the Type and execute an approprate function ( using switch case :) ) Stecya solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) to get array of types

```
    ObservableCollection<Type1> sample = new ObservableCollection<Type1>();
    var types = sample.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
```